# Good strategy to share secrets between client-server builds

Tags: security, tfs, build, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Take the following case as example.

You've a RESTful API layer secured using OAuth2. In the other hand, to let users authenticate against your APIs, you need to request an access token (i.e. `grant_type=password`).

In order to request a password access token, client app requires an OAuth Client (key+secret pair).

Now you've configured everything to use *continuous integration* and *continuous deployment*.

During a development *build*, the *build script* creates test data, including *OAuth clients*. Obviously, if a build creates test data, it previously drops all data created during automated tests.

So you'll want your client app to use one of *OAuth clients* and you want to avoid hardcoding one of them, because they're created using the API infrastructure, so they're re-created from scratch on each build.

Think that front-end and back-end are built by different build scripts.

### Conclusion & question

**What would be a good approach to share secrets between the server and client infrastructure, so both get up and running synchronized with the same security secrets?**

#### Some ideas

1. Operating system environment variables. I could store those secrets on build machine environment variables. That is, client infrastructure will be always built and deployed with most up-to-date secrets.
2. Same as #1, but storing those secrets on a shared directory in the build machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've ended up with the *common build directory to store a JSON file with latest credentials approach* where both builds can access it. Each backend build run persists a JSON file containing the whole credentials, and frontend build relies on the whole file.

Anyway, I tried the environment variables' approach, but since both builds are running on the same TFS build agent, client build couldn't see environment variables' changes unless the whole agent service would be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding TFS/VSTS build (TFS 2015 or later)/release (TFS 2017 or VSTS) system, you just need to check Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token option in Options/General tab of build definition or release environment, then you can fetch Access OAuth Token by using $(System.AccessToekn) in each task.

[image]

[image]

Regarding other system, the better approach is to store the access token in system environment variables and remove it at the end, which is similar to the share variable value for other build/release tasks by using ["##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue"](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) (PowerShell) in TFS or VSTS.

On the other hand, you can store encrypted Access Token in system environment for security, then decrypt and use it.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your effort. It seems like the first part of your answer isn't answering my question at all. I'm not trying to share a TFS access token, it's about sharing a bearer token required by my own infrastructure. In the other hand, I was trying the environment variables' approach, but I wasn't working well because, since both client app and backend builds work on the same build agent, I wasn't able to see updatedenvironment variable until restarting the agent service... So I ended up serializing these credentials to JSON and then I'm storing files in a common known place

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer serialize token to JSON is ok, you can post an answer.

Comment: I see. I've added it. Anyway, I appreciate your effort!